# Short term coordinates based on last GPS location and sensors

Tags: android, geolocation, gps

I am developing an app, where I need (GPS) coordinates every couple of seconds, unfortunately the GPS uses a lot of battery.

Is it possible to get a good estimated position (including altitude) based on the last GPS position(s) and motion sensors from an Android smartphone, for let's say 1 minute?
What algorithms would I need to look into?

Answer (score 1):

This does not work with GPS.
The GPS chip has to track the sattelites all the time, so it makes no difference for battery consumption if you get once a minute or once a second.
Things changes when you only need a position evry 5 minutes, then it could make sense to stop location service, and restart again. (but even that is only a vague estimation). 
Finally you have to measure which intervall really saves battery.

bye the way: i can record 8 hours of gps with one fix per second, on iphone 4

Comment: So you are saying that when i request a position, that request does not consume energy, does it not have to translate the signals, do some signal transforming, calculations etc... is that not just the process that requires the energy ?

Comment: if GPS is enabled, then it does not matter if you request once a second, or once a minute. The chip does all the transforming. power is only saved if the GPS is stopped to track then position. but start and stop of the CHIP evry 20 seconds makes no sense, probably android OS would keep the GPS enabled if you try to start and stop the service evry 20 seconds.

Comment: Thanks you both, that clarifies things a bit.